# ng-grid customrowTemplate classes are not applying for the displayed grid columns in angularJS after upgrade to 1.7.6 from 1.2.16

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, reactjs, upgrade

I can't applying cellClass dynamically at the time of loading into grid for the first time, after upgrading AngularJS from 1.2.16 to 1.7.8.

```html
<div ng-class="col.colIndex()"
         class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}} />
```

Recently I have upgraded AngularJS version from 1.2.16 to 1.7.8.
after replaced all the angularJS files, every thing working fine apart from Grid alignment. When we scroll towards left it is working fine means unhide columns class are loading properly.
this happen only after upgrade previously working fine.